# Facebooker error although not installed (heroku db:migrate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I use OmniAuth but not Facebooker and this is why I'm going crazy with this error when deploying to heroku. The app crashes instantly and I get this error which I looked all over the internet for but could not solve. Maybe you have an idea:

```
   2013-06-21T08:01:57.114204+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-06-21T08:02:10.368768+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 42262`
2013-06-21T08:02:12.281767+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/facebooker-1.0.75/lib/facebooker/adapters/adapter_base.rb:6:in `<class:AdapterBase>': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions (NameError)
2013-06-21T08:02:12.736090+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/facebooker-1.0.75/lib/facebooker/adapters/adapter_base.rb:3:in `<module:Facebooker>'
2013-06-21T08:02:12.841513+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/facebooker-1.0.75/lib/facebooker/adapters/adapter_base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2013-06-21T08:02:12.941309+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/facebooker-1.0.75/lib/facebooker.rb:259:in `require'
2013-06-21T08:02:13.048146+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/facebooker-1.0.75/lib/facebooker.rb:259:in `<top (required)>'
2013-06-21T08:02:13.147354+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
2013-06-21T08:02:13.246417+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2013-06-21T08:02:13.345101+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
2013-06-21T08:02:13.443960+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
2013-06-21T08:02:13.555103+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
2013-06-21T08:02:13.653827+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
2013-06-21T08:02:13.753646+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
2013-06-21T08:02:13.852584+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2013-06-21T08:02:13.951759+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
2013-06-21T08:02:13.401385+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-06-21T08:02:14.051043+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-06-21T08:02:13.410972+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-06-21T08:02:14.150368+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-06-21T08:02:14.251013+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
```

The real strange thing is that it refers to the facebooker gem 1.0.75 which I do not even have in my gemfile, nor installed.

Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
end


gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', "~> 1.4.0"
```

My application.rb file works perfectly on development, no issues at all.
I cannot reproduce this and am pretty much clueless.

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
    activesupport (3.2.11)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    aws-sdk (1.8.3.1)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      uuidtools (~> 2.1)
    builder (3.0.4)
    cocaine (0.4.2)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    faraday (0.8.7)
      multipart-post (~> 1.1)
    hashie (2.0.5)
    hike (1.2.3)
    httpauth (0.2.0)
    i18n (0.6.4)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (3.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.0)
    jwt (0.1.8)
      multi_json (>= 1.5)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.23)
    multi_json (1.7.7)
    multipart-post (1.2.0)
    nokogiri (1.5.6)
    oauth2 (0.8.1)
      faraday (~> 0.8)
      httpauth (~> 0.1)
      jwt (~> 0.1.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    omniauth (1.1.4)
      hashie (>= 1.2, < 3)
      rack
    omniauth-facebook (1.4.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.0.2)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.3)
      oauth2 (~> 0.8.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
    paperclip (3.4.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.4.0)
      mime-types
    pg (0.15.1)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.11)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      activerecord (= 3.2.11)
      activeresource (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.11)
    railties (3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.0.4)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.2.9)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.7)
    thor (0.18.1)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.14)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (2.1.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    uuidtools (2.1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  aws-sdk
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  jquery-rails
  omniauth-facebook (= 1.4.0)
  paperclip (~> 3.0)
  pg
  rails (= 3.2.11)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  sqlite3
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the line 7 of config/application.rb ? For the facebook-gem, it's a dependency of "omniauth-facebook", that's why it's installed.

Comment: Side note - you may want to consider running Postgres in development as well. Could save you from some major headaches down the road

Comment: I don't get it - why is heroku running Installing facebooker (1.0.75) although I don't use it?

Comment: any idea how to solve this?

Comment: check your Gemfile.lock for any mention of facebooker.

Comment: there is none, gemfile.lock attached in OP

there is trace of some gems I never used in my app (but in other apps), like nokogiri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
It turned out that I initialised a wrong branch and was pushing some old code the whole time.

Comment: Solved!
It turned out that I initialised a wrong branch and was pushing some old code the whole time.